# How to find the 2 inputs, given the solution and a midpoint of the 2 inputs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this problem bandwidth problem

Given $B = fh - fl$ where $B$ is the bandwidth and $fh$ is the highest frequency and $fl$ is the lowest frequency.

if $B = 200$ and midpoint of $fh$ and $fl$ is $140$, what is $fh$ and $fl$ ?

I know answer by using pure common sense, but I dont know how to express it mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you already know that bandwidth is the difference between the highest and the lowest frequency. Write this as

$$B = fh - fl = 200$$

Given that the midpoint is 140, write this as

$$\frac{fh + fl}{2} = 140$$.

Since you already know the answer by common sense, but only wanted help to write it out, I have just written out the simultaneous equations which can be easily solved.

Comment: I tried to solve it, but not sure if i got the right algebra,, fh = 280 - fl , when substituting  280 - fl, I got (280 -fl) / 2 + fl = 140 , but I got fl = 0 , something seems wrong

Comment: You are substituting back in the same equation. If you get fh = 280 - fl from the second one, now put this value of fh in the first, so you get 280 - fl - fl = 200, which will give 2fl = 80, fl - 40 and thus fh = 240.

Comment: Ops, my bad, XD I should substitute it to B = fh - fl ,, I got it now, thank you   for the help..